# Geolocation in app, android

Tags: android, geolocation, broadcastreceiver

I want to add geolocation in my app. For example, I set point on map, set radius, and when I will be in this place, my app must send to user a notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow following link to implement Geo-fencing. The Example code sends notification when user's map marker leaves the Geo-Fence. You can use this code implement your logic to make code to send notification when user's marker enters or touch the fence co-ordinates.

Please do send your code if your successfully. It will be helpful for others. :)

and for your notification purpose use GCM (Google Cloud Messaging)
Here are the links,
[GCM](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) and 
[Geo Fence](http://java.dzone.com/articles/android-geofencing-google-maps)

Answer (score 0):

There's several ways to do this, but you could start reading about [Geofences](http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html) and trying to adapt the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this for map:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start
& read about Geofences on developer page.

For push notifications read [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html).